# CUDA program crashed driver

Tags: c++, cuda

i am trying to make a pice of code work in parallel on a cuda device, but i am having a problem, my gfx driver keep crashing while the program runs, but only for this program, other cuda code runs fine. And it gives a wrong anwser, but i will think that is because of the crash!

Note: it is being runed on a Quadro 2000M GFX card!

Here is my parallel version of the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

#define N 16
#define threads 512
#define MaxBlocks 6500

__global__ void cudaCalculateBestPath(int *M, int *bestToDiagPathSum, int *bestFromDiagPathSum, 
        unsigned int *bestToDiagPathCode, unsigned int *bestFromDiagPathCode)
{
    int x = ((unsigned int)1 << (N-1));
    unsigned int currentPathCode = blockIdx.x * threads + threadIdx.x;
    // This while is for if we are over the max amount of blocks
    while(currentPathCode < x)
    {
        int test = ((unsigned int)1 << (N-1));
        if(currentPathCode >= test)
            return;

        unsigned int ui = currentPathCode;

        int toDiagPathSum = M[0];
        int toDiagRow = 0; 
        int toDiagCol = 0;

        int fromDiagPathSum = M[(N-1)*N+N-1];
        int fromDiagRow = N-1;
        int fromDiagCol = N-1;

        for (int i = 0; i < N-1; i++) 
        {
            if (ui % 2 == 0) 
            {
                toDiagCol++;                 // horizontal move
                fromDiagCol--;
            }
            else                            
            {
                toDiagRow++;                 // vertical move
                fromDiagRow--;
            }
            toDiagPathSum += M[toDiagRow*N+toDiagCol];
            fromDiagPathSum += M[fromDiagRow*N+fromDiagCol];
            ui = ui >> 1;
        }

        if (toDiagPathSum < bestToDiagPathSum[toDiagRow]) 
        {
            bestToDiagPathSum[toDiagRow] = toDiagPathSum;
            bestToDiagPathCode[toDiagRow] = currentPathCode; 
        }

        if (fromDiagPathSum < bestFromDiagPathSum[fromDiagRow]) 
        {
            bestFromDiagPathSum[fromDiagRow] = fromDiagPathSum;
            bestFromDiagPathCode[fromDiagRow] = currentPathCode; 
        }

        // Next run
        currentPathCode = blockDim.x + gridDim.x;
    }
}

int main()
{
    clock_t start = clock();

    //--- create and initialize M matrix (including best path) 

    int M[N*N];
    for (int row = 0; row < N; row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < N; col++)
            M[row*N+col] = 2;

#pragma region Test Path
    M[ 0*N+0] = 1;
    M[ 0*N+1] = 1;
    M[ 0*N+2] = 1;
    M[ 1*N+2] = 1;
    M[ 1*N+3] = 1;
    M[ 2*N+3] = 1;
    M[ 3*N+3] = 1;
    M[ 3*N+4] = 1;
    M[ 3*N+5] = 1;
    M[ 3*N+6] = 1;
    M[ 4*N+6] = 1;
    M[ 5*N+6] = 1;
    M[ 6*N+6] = 1;
    M[ 7*N+6] = 1;
    M[ 8*N+6] = 1;
    M[ 9*N+6] = 1;
    M[10*N+6] = 1;
    M[10*N+7] = 1;
    M[10*N+8] = 1;
    M[10*N+9] = 1;
    M[11*N+9] = 1;
    M[11*N+0] = 1;
    M[12*N+0] = 1;
    M[13*N+10] = 1;
    M[13*N+11] = 1;
    M[13*N+12] = 1;
    M[14*N+12] = 1;
    M[15*N+12] = 1;
    M[15*N+13] = 1;
    M[15*N+14] = 1;
    M[15*N+15] = 1;
#pragma endregion Test Path

    //--- create and initialize bestToDiag and bestFromDiag arrays

    int bestToDiagPathSum[N]; 
    int bestFromDiagPathSum[N];

    unsigned int bestToDiagPathCode[N];
    unsigned int bestFromDiagPathCode[N];

    int biggerThanMaxPathSum = 256*N + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        bestToDiagPathSum[i]   = biggerThanMaxPathSum; 
        bestFromDiagPathSum[i] = biggerThanMaxPathSum;
    }

    //--- iterate through path codes, updating bestToDiag and bestFromDiag arrays

    int x = ((unsigned int)1 << (N-1));

    // Trick for celin the total blocks
    int TotalBlocks = (x+threads)/threads;
    if(TotalBlocks > MaxBlocks)
        TotalBlocks = MaxBlocks;

    int *dev_M, *dev_bestToDiagPathSum, *dev_bestFromDiagPathSum;
    unsigned int *dev_bestToDiagPathCode, *dev_bestFromDiagPathCode;

    // allocate memory
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_M, N*N*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_bestToDiagPathSum, N*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_bestFromDiagPathSum, N*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_bestToDiagPathCode, N*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_bestFromDiagPathCode, N*sizeof(int));

    // Copy memory to device
    cudaMemcpy( dev_M, M, N*N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy( dev_bestToDiagPathSum, bestToDiagPathSum, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy( dev_bestFromDiagPathSum, bestFromDiagPathSum, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy( dev_bestToDiagPathCode, bestToDiagPathCode, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy( dev_bestFromDiagPathCode, bestFromDiagPathCode, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // Run code on device
    printf("Blocks: %d\n", TotalBlocks);
    printf("Threads: %d\n\n", threads);
    cudaCalculateBestPath<<<TotalBlocks,threads>>>(dev_M, dev_bestToDiagPathSum, dev_bestFromDiagPathSum, 
        dev_bestToDiagPathCode, dev_bestFromDiagPathCode);

    // Insert code here to run while the GPU is running.

    // Copy the mem back
    cudaMemcpy( M, dev_M, N*N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy( bestToDiagPathSum, dev_bestToDiagPathSum, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy( bestFromDiagPathSum, dev_bestFromDiagPathSum, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy( bestToDiagPathCode, dev_bestToDiagPathCode, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy( bestFromDiagPathCode, dev_bestFromDiagPathCode, N*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    int bestPathSum = biggerThanMaxPathSum;
    unsigned int bestPathCodePrefix;
    unsigned int bestPathCodeSuffix;

    int tempSum;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        tempSum = bestToDiagPathSum[i] + bestFromDiagPathSum[i] - M[i*N+(N-1-i)];
        if (tempSum < bestPathSum)
        {
            bestPathSum = tempSum;
            bestPathCodePrefix = bestToDiagPathCode[i];
            bestPathCodeSuffix = bestFromDiagPathCode[i];
        }
    }

    //--- output best path sum and best path diagram

    printf("Best Path Sum = %d\n\n",bestPathSum);

    M[0] = -M[0];
    int toDiagRow = 0;
    int toDiagCol = 0;
    unsigned int ui = bestPathCodePrefix;
    for (int i = 0; i < N-1; i++) 
    {
        if (ui % 2 == 0) 
            toDiagCol++;                 // horizontal move
        else                            
            toDiagRow++;                 // vertical move
        M[toDiagRow*N+toDiagCol] = -M[toDiagRow*N+toDiagCol];
        ui = ui >> 1;
    }

    M[(N-1)*N+N-1] = -M[(N-1)*N+N-1];
    int fromDiagRow = N-1;
    int fromDiagCol = N-1;
    ui = bestPathCodeSuffix;
    for (int i = 0; i < N-2; i++) 
    {
        if (ui % 2 == 0) 
            fromDiagCol--;                 // horizontal move
        else                            
            fromDiagRow--;                 // vertical move
        M[fromDiagRow*N+fromDiagCol] = -M[fromDiagRow*N+fromDiagCol];
        ui = ui >> 1;
    }

    for (int row = N-1; row >= 0; row--)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col <= N-1; col++)
            if (M[row*N+col] < 0)
            {
                printf("*");
                M[row*N+col] = -M[row*N+col];
            }
            else
                printf("%d",M[row*N+col]); 
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\nTime elapsed: %f", ((double)clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    int dummyReadForPause;
    scanf_s("%d",&dummyReadForPause);

    return 0;
}
```

Sequential code (Working perfect)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

#define N 16
#define threads 512
#define MaxBlocks 6500

int main()
{
    clock_t start = clock();

    //--- create and initialize M matrix (including best path) 

    int M[N*N];
    for (int row = 0; row < N; row++)
        for (int col = 0; col < N; col++)
            M[row*N+col] = 2;

#pragma region Test Path
    M[ 0*N+0] = 1;
    M[ 0*N+1] = 1;
    M[ 0*N+2] = 1;
    M[ 1*N+2] = 1;
    M[ 1*N+3] = 1;
    M[ 2*N+3] = 1;
    M[ 3*N+3] = 1;
    M[ 3*N+4] = 1;
    M[ 3*N+5] = 1;
    M[ 3*N+6] = 1;
    M[ 4*N+6] = 1;
    M[ 5*N+6] = 1;
    M[ 6*N+6] = 1;
    M[ 7*N+6] = 1;
    M[ 8*N+6] = 1;
    M[ 9*N+6] = 1;
    M[10*N+6] = 1;
    M[10*N+7] = 1;
    M[10*N+8] = 1;
    M[10*N+9] = 1;
    M[11*N+9] = 1;
    M[11*N+0] = 1;
    M[12*N+0] = 1;
    M[13*N+10] = 1;
    M[13*N+11] = 1;
    M[13*N+12] = 1;
    M[14*N+12] = 1;
    M[15*N+12] = 1;
    M[15*N+13] = 1;
    M[15*N+14] = 1;
    M[15*N+15] = 1;
#pragma endregion Test Path

    //--- create and initialize bestToDiag and bestFromDiag arrays

    int bestToDiagPathSum[N]; 
    int bestFromDiagPathSum[N];

    unsigned int bestToDiagPathCode[N];
    unsigned int bestFromDiagPathCode[N];

    int biggerThanMaxPathSum = 256*N + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        bestToDiagPathSum[i]   = biggerThanMaxPathSum; 
        bestFromDiagPathSum[i] = biggerThanMaxPathSum;
    }

    //--- iterate through path codes, updating bestToDiag and bestFromDiag arrays
    int toDiagPathSum, toDiagRow, toDiagCol;
    int fromDiagPathSum, fromDiagRow, fromDiagCol;
    unsigned int ui;
    int x = ((unsigned int)1 << (N-1));

    for(unsigned int currentPathCode = 0; currentPathCode < x; currentPathCode++)
    {
        ui = currentPathCode;

        toDiagPathSum = M[0];
        toDiagRow = 0; 
        toDiagCol = 0;

        fromDiagPathSum = M[(N-1)*N+N-1];
        fromDiagRow = N-1;
        fromDiagCol = N-1;

        for (int i = 0; i < N-1; i++) 
        {
            if (ui % 2 == 0) 
            {
                toDiagCol++;                 // horizontal move
                fromDiagCol--;
            }
            else                            
            {
                toDiagRow++;                 // vertical move
                fromDiagRow--;
            }
            toDiagPathSum += M[toDiagRow*N+toDiagCol];
            fromDiagPathSum += M[fromDiagRow*N+fromDiagCol];
            ui = ui >> 1;
        }

        if (toDiagPathSum < bestToDiagPathSum[toDiagRow]) 
        {
            bestToDiagPathSum[toDiagRow] = toDiagPathSum;
            bestToDiagPathCode[toDiagRow] = currentPathCode; 
        }

        if (fromDiagPathSum < bestFromDiagPathSum[fromDiagRow]) 
        {
            bestFromDiagPathSum[fromDiagRow] = fromDiagPathSum;
            bestFromDiagPathCode[fromDiagRow] = currentPathCode; 
        }
    }

    int bestPathSum = biggerThanMaxPathSum;
    unsigned int bestPathCodePrefix;
    unsigned int bestPathCodeSuffix;

    int tempSum;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        tempSum = bestToDiagPathSum[i] + bestFromDiagPathSum[i] - M[i*N+(N-1-i)];
        if (tempSum < bestPathSum)
        {
            bestPathSum = tempSum;
            bestPathCodePrefix = bestToDiagPathCode[i];
            bestPathCodeSuffix = bestFromDiagPathCode[i];
        }
    }

    //--- output best path sum and best path diagram

    printf("Best Path Sum = %d\n\n",bestPathSum);

    M[0] = -M[0];
    toDiagRow = 0;
    toDiagCol = 0;
    ui = bestPathCodePrefix;
    for (int i = 0; i < N-1; i++) 
    {
        if (ui % 2 == 0) 
            toDiagCol++;                 // horizontal move
        else                            
            toDiagRow++;                 // vertical move
        M[toDiagRow*N+toDiagCol] = -M[toDiagRow*N+toDiagCol];
        ui = ui >> 1;
    }

    M[(N-1)*N+N-1] = -M[(N-1)*N+N-1];
    fromDiagRow = N-1;
    fromDiagCol = N-1;
    ui = bestPathCodeSuffix;
    for (int i = 0; i < N-2; i++) 
    {
        if (ui % 2 == 0) 
            fromDiagCol--;                 // horizontal move
        else                            
            fromDiagRow--;                 // vertical move
        M[fromDiagRow*N+fromDiagCol] = -M[fromDiagRow*N+fromDiagCol];
        ui = ui >> 1;
    }

    for (int row = N-1; row >= 0; row--)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col <= N-1; col++)
            if (M[row*N+col] < 0)
            {
                printf("*");
                M[row*N+col] = -M[row*N+col];
            }
            else
                printf("%d",M[row*N+col]); 
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\nTime elapsed: %f", ((double)clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    int dummyReadForPause;
    scanf_s("%d",&dummyReadForPause);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just as an observation, your CUDA code seems awfully complex. Is it clear that each thread is accessing separate memory locations? Branching inside the parallel code is discouraged, but you are also modifying the index variable (`ui`) inside the code... that looks very suspicious.

Comment: If i lower the N number, to a low number like 6, dose it worke fine, but i if gets higher dose it crash, i think it might be a watchdog problem, but how to fix it is beond me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a long running kernel Windows will stop your driver to prevent the system from becoming unresponsive. You will need to do some regedit to remove this feature. Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487368.aspx